# What should I do to port GCC compiler to Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, windows-phone-8

I want to start up with writing a Windows Phone 8 Application which compiles C/C++ code on the Phone itself.

The questions I want to ask are:

1. Is it possible to do so ?
2. How should I start up with this project?

Comment: 1. yes, 2. probably you shouldn't if you don't already know where/how to begin.

Comment: what is your background maybe you should start with an easier project

Comment: @BarışAkkurt I am not a computer-science engineer, neither a hardcore programmer. The windows phone store lacks a C++ compiler. Though I understand what you want to say.

Comment: Simply building GCC on a _supported_ platform is a nightmare already, even for someone who is somehow experienced. I wouldn't even want to think about porting it...

Comment: @mozart [Here's a paper](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/gcc-v3.pdf) that describes the porting process - unfortunately, it's not trivial (as I've already mentioned it once on Stack Overflow: porting a compiler is hard, if it isn't GCC then that's why, if it is GCC, then that's why.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I was already reading this article.

Comment: The problem is that Windows Phone applications are sandboxed, so I'm fairly sure that even if you could compile the code, you could not actually execute it unless you're compiling for an emulator that is also running on the phone. That adds another complexity.

Comment: Or you would have to get Microsoft to sign your executable with their super-uber-key, which allows you to bypass the sandbox (like IE does). But I wouldn't wager my house that they'll do that.

Comment: For what it's worth, I understand that it would probably take less effort to get LLVM/Clang to a new target, instead of porting GCC. However, this process is still very non-trivial, and as others have mentioned may not even be possible on Windows Phone.